# Copy scopes in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

When I working in Sublime Text 3, I direct caret at a syntax element and I press on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>. In the Status Bar shows the scopes syntax.

[image: Scopes in Status Bar]

How can I copy scopes?

I googled and found 2 solutions: [copy_scope_to_clipboard](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/how-to-copy-the-scope/1259/2) and [cope_scope](https://gist.github.com/ttscoff/2721811) plugins. I established these plugins, but they don't work for me. Perhaps, the reason that these plugins are written for Sublime Text 2, but I use Sublime Text 3.

Thanks.

Comment: You could try [ScopeHunter](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ScopeHunter)

Comment: @r-stein, ScopeHunter [don't work for me](https://github.com/facelessuser/ScopeHunter/issues/30).

Comment: If you open the sublime console `` ctrl+` `` and write `sublime.set_clipboard(view.scope_name(view.sel()[0].b))` it should copy the scope under the first cursor to the clipboard.

Comment: @r-stein, thank you very much! Please, write your comment as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to copy the scope under the cursor, you can open the ST console `` ctrl+` `` and write `sublime.set_clipboard(view.scope_name(view.sel()[0].b))`. This extracts the scope under the first cursor and writes it to the clipboard.

If you want to pack it into a plugin just open `Tools >>> New Plugin...` and paste:

```py
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class CopyScopeCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        view = self.view
        sublime.set_clipboard(view.scope_name(view.sel()[0].b))
        sublime.status_message("Scope copied")
```

Afterwards paste this to your keymap to bind it to the keybinding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>:

```js
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+alt+shift+c"],
    "command": "copy_scope",
},
```